# Hook into rendered templates?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, hook

I am hoping to write a plug-in to cache pages as static HTML. Is there a hook that would give me access to the full rendered HTML of a page?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, no.  But it is on our radar and we've got some ideas on how we'd want to implement it.

Comment: Did you ever work on this @BradBell ? We have written our own Full Page Cache plugin for a live project, but would be interested in and changes that might help improve it!

Comment: Nope, still on our radar, though.  Feel free to share the plugin!

Comment: Cool thanks, absolutely will do, just needs a bit of tidying before release (just like the other handful of plugins we would love to release). Dam client work :)